# What to sign for DTLSv1.0 Certificate Verify Message with RSA

Tags: certificate, rsa, dtls

I'm using `DTLS v1.0` to communicate with a server. I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly what to do to generate the `certificate verify message`. I've been reading the `RFCs` ([DTLSv1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347) and [TLS1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346), which DTLS v1.0 is based on) but they're somewhat non-specific when it comes to this particular message.

I see the structure of the message is as below, and I know the signature type is `RSA`.

> ```
> struct {
>        Signature signature;   
> } CertificateVerify;
> ```
>
> The Signature type is defined in 7.4.3.
>
> ```
> CertificateVerify.signature.md5_hash
>       MD5(handshake_messages);
>
> CertificateVerify.signature.sha_hash
>       SHA(handshake_messages);
> ```

Based on what I've read it seems to be a concatenation of the `sha1` hash and the `md5` hash of all the previous messages sent and received (up to and excluding this one) and then `RSA` signed.

The piece that's got me a bit confused though is how to assemble the messages to hash them.

Does it use each fragment piece or does it use the re-assembled messages? Also, what parts of the messages does it use?

The RFC for TLS 1.1 says

> starting at client hello up to but not including this message,
> including the type and length fields of the handshake messages

but what about the DTLS specific parts like `message_seq`, `fragment_offset`, and `fragment_length`, do I include them?

UPDATE:
I have tried doing as the RFC for [DTLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.6) shows (meaning keeping the messages fragmented, using all the handshake fields including `DTLS` specific fields, and not including the initial `Client Hello` or `Hello Verify Request` messages) but I am still receiving "Bad Signature". I do believe I'm signing properly, so it's my belief that I'm concatenating the data improperly to be signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DTLS 1.2 it is defined. And reading RFC 4347, my impression is, RFC 6347 doesn't differ, it clarifies the calculations.

[RFC 6347, 4.2.6. CertificateVerify and Finished Messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6347#section-4.2.6)

[RFC 4347, 4.2.6. Finished Messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347#section-4.2.6)

Comment: That actually doesn't seem to be working for me (or I'm missing something else). I'm using all parts of the handshake message (type, length, sequence, fragment offset, and fragment length), I'm treating each fragment as it's own message (the RFC shows that the Finished MAC needs to have the fragments reassembled but not for the certificate verify). I'm making sure to exclude the client hello with no cookie and the hello verify request. I do believe I'm signing properly but I continue to get "Bad RSA Signature". Are we sure 1.2 is just clarifying? I can't seem to find any info elsewhere

Comment: > (the RFC shows that the Finished MAC needs to have the fragments reassembled but not for the certificate verify). Maybe you try to ask the IETF TLS mailing list for that. [IETF TLS](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/tls). I only use/support DTLS 1.2 RFC6347. There the fragments are always reassembled, also for the certificate verify.

Comment: "Are we sure 1.2 is just clarifying?", no, I'm not sure. It's just my assumption, mainly because the new RFC 6347 contains an explanation, why the fragments are reassembled before they used for the sha. I'm not sure, why you want to stick to use the fragments. I would try out to use the reassembled handshake messages also for the certificate verify. That maybe a "short-cut" before asking the IETF tls mailing list.

Comment: I thought I had tried using the reassembled messages but I must have had something wrong. I tried it again and it is in fact working. Thank you!