# RSA Signature with MD5+SHA1 hash in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, md5, digital-signature, sha1

I need to `RSA sign` some data using a combination of the `MD5` and `SHA1` hashes. I can easily do this for just one or the other but having a combination makes it tricky. It's for the `certificate verify` message in `DTLS 1.0`, so it's not like I can just choose to do just one unfortunately.

I believe the steps to be to hash in `MD5`, then hash in `SHA1` and concatenate. Then I need to encrypt with the private key. That's where I'm stuck.

I have an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` that has the proper private key (it's not exportable). I know I cannot do

```
rsa.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

because it's not just a SHA1 hash so this function sees the hash as invalid since it's 36 bytes instead of 20 bytes as expected.

I also know I cannot do

```
rsa.SignData(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

because that's going to hash again.

I believe I'm closer with

```
rsa.Encrypt(hash, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

however that's using the public key instead of the private key like I need.

Any suggests on how I can either encrypt with the private key or do the signing with MD5+SHA1?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported. You have to write your own with [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.1). Sounds horrible. Good luck.

Comment: So i actually saw another question that said that, but the problem is that the private key is not exportable so I can't access the exponent or modulus 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407581/rsa-signing-using-md5-sha1-hash-algorithm

Comment: The Microsoft sample code is really bad.  You need to add the same private key when encrypting and decrypting and sample only how how to generate a random key.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container

Comment: So create a new private key that is exportable. If you close off all avenues to solve your problem then you won't get it solved.

Comment: It's not my key, I have no control over that. There's no other way?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Perhaps user bartonjs, who is an expert on Microsoft cryptography, will stop by and figure something out.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'll see if there's anyway we can get the key marked exportable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in the managed layer, but you can get the native layer to do it for you.

Given that you already have a persisted key in RSACryptoServiceProvider format (named `rsaCsp`) and your data to be signed (named `toBeSigned`) you can

- Re-open the CAPI key in CNG (almost always works)
- Ask CNG to do the signing for you

  - By not specifying a hash algorithm name it assumes you've done whatever data framing is required.  In your case, just concatenating the data and not framing it in a DigestInfo.

Sounds tricky, but it isn't, really.

```
byte[] md5;
byte[] sha1;

using (HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create())
{
    md5 = hash.ComputeHash(toBeSigned);
}

using (HashAlgorithm hash = SHA1.Create())
{
    sha1 = hash.ComputeHash(toBeSigned);
}

byte[] all = md5.Concat(sha1).ToArray();
CspKeyContainerInfo cspInfo = rsaCsp.CspKeyContainerInfo;
CngProvider provider = new CngProvider(cspInfo.ProviderName);
CngKeyOpenOptions options = CngKeyOpenOptions.None;

if (cspInfo.MachineKeyStore)
{
    options = CngKeyOpenOptions.MachineKey;
}

using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(cspInfo.KeyContainerName, provider, options))
{
    return NCryptInterop.SignHashRaw(cngKey, all, rsaCsp.KeySize);
}
```

That requires you do a tiny bit if Interop work:

```
private static class NCryptInterop
{
    private struct BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO
    {
        internal IntPtr pszAlgId;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum NCryptSignFlags
    {
        BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1 = 2,
    }

    [DllImport("ncrypt.dll")]
    private static extern int NCryptSignHash(
        SafeNCryptKeyHandle hKey,
        ref BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO padding,
        ref byte pbHashValue,
        int cbHashValue,
        ref byte pbSignature,
        int cbSignature,
        out int cbResult,
        NCryptSignFlags dwFlags);

    internal static byte[] SignHashRaw(CngKey key, byte[] hash, int keySize)
    {
        int keySizeBytes = keySize / 8;
        byte[] signature = new byte[keySizeBytes];

        // The Handle property returns a new object each time.
        using (SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle = key.Handle)
        {
            // Leave pszAlgId NULL to "raw sign"
            BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO paddingInfo = new BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO();

            int result = NCryptSignHash(
                keyHandle,
                ref paddingInfo,
                ref hash[0],
                hash.Length,
                ref signature[0],
                signature.Length,
                out int cbResult,
                NCryptSignFlags.BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException(result);
            }

            if (cbResult != signature.Length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            return signature;
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically it'd be possible to do it with CAPI, too (if your private key happens to live in an HSM that has no CNG driver)... but then you have to play with a lot more pointers.  The CngKey type really saves you a lot of work here.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd have an answer for my other question on how to specifically build the message to be hashed?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220762/what-to-sign-for-dtlsv1-0-certificate-verify-message-with-rsa